# Non-measurable bijection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions

I wanted to find a non-measurable bijection $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Of course it must be non-continuous so I thought of taking a Vitali set $V\subset(0,1)$ and defining  $$f(x)=\cases{ x & if $x\leq 0$ \\ x & if $x \in (0,1) \cap V^C$ \\ x+1 & if $x \in V$ \\x+1 & if $x\geq 1$} $$
We can verify that $f^{-1}((1,2))=V$ so $f$ is not measurable but it is a bijection.
However, I know that some of you usually come up with simpler/easier/creative/ more beautiful counterexamples so I wanted to find out what other examples of such functions can be constructed. (Of course I think we can have uncountably many other examples by taking a continuous bijection $f$ and shifting a non measurable part of the image by a constant upwards...)

Comment: You might be interested in [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42215/does-constructing-non-measurable-sets-require-the-axiom-of-choice) on the connection between the existence of non-measurable sets and the axiom of choice. Depending on your definitions of simpler/easier/creative/beautiful you may decided that either this thread says that the answer is no, or gives you a hint towards creating your own examples

Comment: @DavidSheard Thank you but honestly I was just looking for some fancy or funny constructions of non-measurable bijections, the existence of the non-measurable set $V$ is admitted. Or maybe I didn't understand the link of the discussion you sent with my question.

Comment: Your example is not surjective.  It misses some of the values between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: @GEdgar yes you're right. That function was not my first thought when I wrote, I wanted to write in a cleaner way. I think I can fix it by still taking $x$ on $(0,1) \cap V^C$, $x+1$ on $V$ then $x-1$ on $V+1$ and $x$ on $(1,2) \cap (V+1)^C$

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by taking $f(x)=x+1$ if $x \in V$ and $f(x)=x-1$ if $x \in V+1$, with $f(x)=x$ if $x \notin V\cup(V+1)$.